# Where can I get a list of all emotional words ranked?

Tags: emotions

I am looking for a list of all emotional words ranked in terms of emotive / emotional value.

Where can I get it?

Or any site which gives a rating of a word typed.

Thank you!

Comment: This may not be the best forum to answer such.

Comment: What do you mean by ranked and rated? Words denote or connote emotion-related meaning. I just don't think you can proceed like this.

Answer (score 1):

Charles Egerton Osgood's book *Cross-cultural universals of affective meaning* (Urbana, University of Illinois Press, 1975) contains an appendix which ranks several thousand affective words based on the semantic differential scale.

There are other sources for word corpus which contain frequencies of words that aren't broken out as 'emotional.' For instance:

-Corpus of Contemporary American English  https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/

-Word frequency data: https://www.wordfrequency.info/

-Peter Norvig's exhaustive list of word frequencies http://norvig.com/google-books-common-words.txt

His website has other potentially useful lists  http://norvig.com/